# Different starting indices for slices in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I'm wondering if it's possible without iterating with a for loop to do something like this:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 5, 3, 4],
              [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])

cleaver = np.argmax(a == 5, axis=1)  # np.array([2, 1])

foo(a, cleaver)

>>> np.array([False, False, True, True, True],
             [False, True, True, True, True])
```

Is there a way to accomplish this through slicing or some other non-iterative function? The arrays I'm using are quite large and iterating over them row by row is prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) *magic* -

```
cleaver[:,None] <= np.arange(a.shape[1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [60]: a
Out[60]: 
array([[1, 2, 5, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [61]: cleaver
Out[61]: array([2, 1])

In [62]: cleaver[:,None] <= np.arange(a.shape[1])
Out[62]: 
array([[False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```